# Structural XML issue in R

Tags: r, xml

I'm trying to process a XML file to extract data.

I make a `xmlTreeParse`:

```
library(XML)
result <- xmlTreeParse(paste0("C:/Users/XXXXX/Desktop/BDD/YYYYYY/2019/04/", list[1]),
                       options=NOCDATA)
```

XML

```
<page numero="01">
    <liasse code="AN" m1="000000000721539" m2="000000000261294" m3="000000000460245" m4="000000000489339"/>
    <liasse code="AP" m1="000000003002653" m2="000000002343665" m3="000000000658988" m4="000000000735758"/>
    <liasse code="AR" m1="000000003542821" m2="000000002684604" m3="000000000858216" m4="000000000610309"/>
    <liasse code="AT" m1="000000003248751" m2="000000002179489" m3="000000001069263" m4="000000000762698"/>
    <liasse code="AV" m1="000000000068805" m3="000000000068805" m4="000000000012409"/>
    <liasse code="CU" m1="000000000060010" m3="000000000060010" m4="000000000061810"/>
    <liasse code="BH" m1="000000000089574" m3="000000000089574" m4="000000000085296"/>
    <liasse code="A4" m1="000000000439046" m3="000000000439046" m4="000000000375654"/>
    <liasse code="BJ" m1="000000011752914" m2="000000007901826" m3="000000003851088" m4="000000003250029"/>
    <liasse code="BV" m1="000000000001595" m3="000000000001595" m4="000000000050099"/>
    <liasse code="BX" m1="000000012674765" m2="000000000142007" m3="000000012532758" m4="000000014301355"/>
    <liasse code="BZ" m1="000000003906347" m3="000000003906347" m4="000000003729111"/>
    <liasse code="CF" m1="000000006998725" m3="000000006998725" m4="000000006081410"/>
    <liasse code="CJ" m1="000000026381479" m2="000000000142007" m3="000000026239472" m4="000000026166270"/>
    <liasse code="CO" m1="000000038134393" m2="000000008043833" m3="000000030090560" m4="000000029416299"/>
   </page>
   <page numero="02">
    <liasse code="DA" m1="000000000534780" m2="000000000534792"/>
    <liasse code="DB" m1="000000000006860" m2="000000000006860"/>
    <liasse code="DD" m1="000000007670605" m2="000000007158735"/>
    <liasse code="DH" m1="000000000000725" m2="000000000000745"/>
    <liasse code="P2" m1="000000002134033" m2="000000002455814"/>
    <liasse code="DL" m1="000000010346925" m2="000000010156947"/>
    <liasse code="P5" m1="000000001165756" m2="000000001047608"/>
    <liasse code="P6" m1="000000001427476" m2="000000001451592"/>
    <liasse code="P7" m1="000000002593232" m2="000000002499200"/>
    <liasse code="DR" m1="000000000094988" m2="000000000205844"/>
    <liasse code="DV" m1="000000001310000" m2="000000001480000"/>
    <liasse code="DW" m1="000000000007162" m2="000000000002101"/>
    <liasse code="DX" m1="000000006419992" m2="000000006113866"/>
    <liasse code="DY" m1="000000008430983" m2="000000008657123"/>
    <liasse code="EA" m1="000000000887277" m2="000000000301219"/>
    <liasse code="EC" m1="000000017055414" m2="000000016554309"/>
    <liasse code="EE" m1="000000030090560" m2="000000029416299"/>
</page>
```

Then, I transform *result* into a list with:

```
a <- xmlToList(result)
```

After that, *a* is equivalent to:

```
[[2]]$page
[[2]]$page$liasse
             code                m1                m2                m3                m4 
             "AN" "000000000721539" "000000000261294" "000000000460245" "000000000489339" 

[[2]]$page$liasse
             code                m1                m2                m3                m4 
             "AP" "000000003002653" "000000002343665" "000000000658988" "000000000735758" 

[[2]]$page$liasse
             code                m1                m2                m3                m4 
             "AR" "000000003542821" "000000002684604" "000000000858216" "000000000610309" 

[[2]]$page$liasse
             code                m1                m2                m3                m4 
             "AT" "000000003248751" "000000002179489" "000000001069263" "000000000762698" 

[[2]]$page$liasse
             code                m1                m3                m4 
             "AV" "000000000068805" "000000000068805" "000000000012409" 

[[2]]$page$liasse
             code                m1                m3                m4 
             "CU" "000000000060010" "000000000060010" "000000000061810" 

[[2]]$page$liasse
             code                m1                m3                m4 
             "BH" "000000000089574" "000000000089574" "000000000085296" 

[[2]]$page$liasse
             code                m1                m3                m4 
             "A4" "000000000439046" "000000000439046" "000000000375654" 

[[2]]$page$liasse
             code                m1                m2                m3                m4 
             "BJ" "000000011752914" "000000007901826" "000000003851088" "000000003250029" 

[[2]]$page$liasse
             code                m1                m3                m4 
             "BV" "000000000001595" "000000000001595" "000000000050099" 

[[2]]$page$liasse
             code                m1                m2                m3                m4 
             "BX" "000000012674765" "000000000142007" "000000012532758" "000000014301355" 

[[2]]$page$liasse
             code                m1                m3                m4 
             "BZ" "000000003906347" "000000003906347" "000000003729111" 

[[2]]$page$liasse
             code                m1                m3                m4 
             "CF" "000000006998725" "000000006998725" "000000006081410" 

[[2]]$page$liasse
             code                m1                m2                m3                m4 
             "CJ" "000000026381479" "000000000142007" "000000026239472" "000000026166270" 

[[2]]$page$liasse
             code                m1                m2                m3                m4 
             "CO" "000000038134393" "000000008043833" "000000030090560" "000000029416299" 

[[2]]$page$.attrs
numero 
  "01" 


[[2]]$page
[[2]]$page[[1]]
[1] "DA"

[[2]]$page[[2]]
[1] "000000000534780"

[[2]]$page[[3]]
[1] "000000000534792"

[[2]]$page[[4]]
[1] "DB"

[[2]]$page[[5]]
[1] "000000000006860"

[[2]]$page[[6]]
[1] "000000000006860"

[[2]]$page[[7]]
[1] "DD"

[[2]]$page[[8]]
[1] "000000007670605"

[[2]]$page[[9]]
[1] "000000007158735"

[[2]]$page[[10]]
[1] "DH"

[[2]]$page[[11]]
[1] "000000000000725"

[[2]]$page[[12]]
[1] "000000000000745"

[[2]]$page[[13]]
[1] "P2"

[[2]]$page[[14]]
[1] "000000002134033"

[[2]]$page[[15]]
[1] "000000002455814"

[[2]]$page[[16]]
[1] "DL"

[[2]]$page[[17]]
[1] "000000010346925"

[[2]]$page[[18]]
[1] "000000010156947"

[[2]]$page[[19]]
[1] "P5"

[[2]]$page[[20]]
[1] "000000001165756"

[[2]]$page[[21]]
[1] "000000001047608"

[[2]]$page[[22]]
[1] "P6"

[[2]]$page[[23]]
[1] "000000001427476"

[[2]]$page[[24]]
[1] "000000001451592"

[[2]]$page[[25]]
[1] "P7"

[[2]]$page[[26]]
[1] "000000002593232"

[[2]]$page[[27]]
[1] "000000002499200"

[[2]]$page[[28]]
[1] "DR"

[[2]]$page[[29]]
[1] "000000000094988"

[[2]]$page[[30]]
[1] "000000000205844"

[[2]]$page[[31]]
[1] "DV"

[[2]]$page[[32]]
[1] "000000001310000"

[[2]]$page[[33]]
[1] "000000001480000"

[[2]]$page[[34]]
[1] "DW"

[[2]]$page[[35]]
[1] "000000000007162"

[[2]]$page[[36]]
[1] "000000000002101"

[[2]]$page[[37]]
[1] "DX"

[[2]]$page[[38]]
[1] "000000006419992"

[[2]]$page[[39]]
[1] "000000006113866"

[[2]]$page[[40]]
[1] "DY"

[[2]]$page[[41]]
[1] "000000008430983"

[[2]]$page[[42]]
[1] "000000008657123"

[[2]]$page[[43]]
[1] "EA"

[[2]]$page[[44]]
[1] "000000000887277"

[[2]]$page[[45]]
[1] "000000000301219"

[[2]]$page[[46]]
[1] "EC"

[[2]]$page[[47]]
[1] "000000017055414"

[[2]]$page[[48]]
[1] "000000016554309"

[[2]]$page[[49]]
[1] "EE"

[[2]]$page[[50]]
[1] "000000030090560"

[[2]]$page[[51]]
[1] "000000029416299"

[[2]]$page$.attrs
numero 
  "02" 


[[2]]$page
[[2]]$page[[1]]
[1] "FJ"

[[2]]$page[[2]]
[1] "000000050120774"

[[2]]$page[[3]]
[1] "000000047322734"

[[2]]$page[[4]]
[1] "FQ"

[[2]]$page[[5]]
[1] "000000001105560"

[[2]]$page[[6]]
[1] "000000000406084"

[[2]]$page[[7]]
[1] "FR"

[[2]]$page[[8]]
[1] "000000051226334"

[[2]]$page[[9]]
[1] "000000047728818"

[[2]]$page[[10]]
[1] "FX"

[[2]]$page[[11]]
[1] "000000001093840"

[[2]]$page[[12]]
[1] "000000000043456"

[[2]]$page[[13]]
[1] "FZ"

[[2]]$page[[14]]
[1] "000000018415747"

[[2]]$page[[15]]
[1] "000000017956251"

[[2]]$page[[16]]
[1] "GA"

[[2]]$page[[17]]
[1] "000000000826189"

[[2]]$page[[18]]
[1] "000000000904242"

[[2]]$page[[19]]
[1] "GE"

[[2]]$page[[20]]
[1] "000000000005947"

[[2]]$page[[21]]
[1] "000000000000160"

[[2]]$page[[22]]
[1] "GF"

[[2]]$page[[23]]
[1] "000000046193245"

[[2]]$page[[24]]
[1] "000000041277940"

[[2]]$page[[25]]
[1] "GG"

[[2]]$page[[26]]
[1] "000000005033090"

[[2]]$page[[27]]
[1] "000000005445878"

[[2]]$page[[28]]
[1] "GV"

[[2]]$page[[29]]
[1] "000000000026085"

[[2]]$page[[30]]
[1] "000000000042067"

[[2]]$page[[31]]
[1] "GW"

[[2]]$page[[32]]
[1] "000000005059175"

[[2]]$page[[33]]
[1] "000000005487945"

[[2]]$page$.attrs
numero 
  "03"
```

When I convert it in list, the structure of the file is different according to page number. A part of data is correctly processed with some "columns" by row (code, m1, m2,...) and the other part contains only one information by row.

I don't know if the problem comes from my code or it's include in the xml file.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for the different type of structures is likely due to the varying *m1-m4* attributes in some *pages* and consistent *m1-m2* attributes on other *pages*. This can be seen if you run `xpathSApply` on child elements where the consistent attributes can be coerced into a matrix and inconsistent ones left as list.

Nonetheless, if your goal is to achieve a data frame of XML data, consider XML's internal variable `xmlAttrsToDataframe` using the triple colon operator:

```
df <- XML:::xmlAttrsToDataFrame(getNodeSet(result, path='//liasse'))
head(df)
#    code              m1              m2              m3              m4
# 1    AN 000000000721539 000000000261294 000000000460245 000000000489339
# 2    AP 000000003002653 000000002343665 000000000658988 000000000735758
# 3    AR 000000003542821 000000002684604 000000000858216 000000000610309
# 4    AT 000000003248751 000000002179489 000000001069263 000000000762698
# 5    AV 000000000068805            <NA> 000000000068805 000000000012409
# 6    CU 000000000060010            <NA> 000000000060010 000000000061810
```

However, if you want to capture the parent *numero* value, you need to parse the *liasse* elements individually under corresponding *page*. Below builds a nested list of data frames that are row binded at the end.

Since `rbind` requires same named columns for concatenated data frames, a trick to return a value for missing attribute is using XPath's `concat` with a zero-length string (later converted to `NA`).

```
page_nums <- xpathSApply(result, "//page", xmlAttrs)

# ITERATE BY PAGE ELEMS USING ATTRIBUTE VALUE
df_list <- lapply(page_nums, function(p){
  liasse_elems <- xpathSApply(result, paste0("//page[@numero='", p ,"']/liasse"))      

  # ITERATE BY LIASSE ELEMS USING NODE POSITION
  liasse_list <- lapply(seq_along(liasse_elems), function(i)
    data.frame(page = p,
               code = xpathSApply(result, paste0("//page[@numero='", p ,"']/liasse[", i ,"]/@code")),
               m1 = xpathSApply(result, paste0("concat(//page[@numero='", p ,"']/liasse[", i ,"]/@m1, '')")),
               m2 = xpathSApply(result, paste0("concat(//page[@numero='", p ,"']/liasse[", i ,"]/@m2, '')")),
               m3 = xpathSApply(result, paste0("concat(//page[@numero='", p ,"']/liasse[", i ,"]/@m3, '')")),
               m4 = xpathSApply(result, paste0("concat(//page[@numero='", p ,"']/liasse[", i ,"]/@m4, '')"))
    )
  )
  data.frame(do.call(rbind, unname(liasse_list)), row.names = NULL)

})

final_df <- do.call(rbind, unname(df_list))
final_df[final_df==""] <- NA
```

**Output**

```
head(final_df)
#   page code              m1              m2              m3              m4
# 1   01   AN 000000000721539 000000000261294 000000000460245 000000000489339
# 2   01   AP 000000003002653 000000002343665 000000000658988 000000000735758
# 3   01   AR 000000003542821 000000002684604 000000000858216 000000000610309
# 4   01   AT 000000003248751 000000002179489 000000001069263 000000000762698
# 5   01   AV 000000000068805            <NA> 000000000068805 000000000012409
# 6   01   CU 000000000060010            <NA> 000000000060010 000000000061810
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer, indeed I try to get a data frame with XML data but:

```
df <- XML:::xmlAttrsToDataFrame(getNodeSet(result, path="//liasse"))
```

> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
>   unable to find an inherited method for function ‘saveXML’ for signature ‘"XMLDocument"’

I've tried to specify the namespace with:

```
  df <- XML:::xmlAttrsToDataFrame(getNodeSet(result, path="//liasse", namespaces = xmlNamespaceDefinitions(result, simplify = T)))
```

> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
>   unable to find an inherited method for function ‘saveXML’ for signature ‘"XMLDocument"’

but it's not the good solution, so I use:

```
result <- xmlTreeParse(paste0("C:/Users/b.rosello/Desktop/BDD/FileZilla/2019/04/",list[1]),options=NOCDATA,useInternalNodes = T)
df <- XML:::xmlAttrsToDataFrame(getNodeSet(result, path="//liasse",xmlValue))
```

But I have a tricky error.

> Error in names(namespaces) <- rep("", length(namespaces)) : 
>   names() applied to a non-vector